# How can I retrieve data from joined tables?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
products table
--------------
id
name
...


categories table
----------------
id
name
...


product_categories table
------------------------
product_id
category_id
```

And join them by this query:

```
select p.*
from products p
join product_categories pc on pc.product_id = p.id
join categories c on pc.category_id = c.id
```

This query return multiple records of a product per each category of that product, but I want to get only one product and multiple category of that product.

This is my output:

```
p.Id  p.name --> cat_id cat_name

1 product_1 --> 1 cat1
1 product_1 --> 3 cat3
1 product_1 --> 2 cat2
1 product_1 --> 6 cat6 
2 product_2 --> 5 cat5
2 product_2 --> 1 cat1 
.
.
.
```

And desired output:

```
p.Id  p.name --> cat_id cat_name,cat_id cat_name,...

1 product_1 --> 1 cat1,3 cat3,2 cat2,6 cat6 
2 product_2 --> 5 cat5,1 cat1 
.
.
.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what ouptput you want show it here. se we will have better understanding

Comment: add a `WHERE` clause. `WHERE p.id = <some id>`

Comment: `SELECT c.*` and use a `WHERE ` clause

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande I want a result like this: `code 1 product_1 cat1,cat3,cat2,cat6 | 2 product_2 cat5,cat1 |... `

Comment: @ughai I want a result like this: `code 1 product_1 cat1,cat3,cat2,cat6 | 2 product_2 cat5,cat1 |... `

Comment: @wewesthemenace I want a result like this: `code 1 product_1 cat1,cat3,cat2,cat6 | 2 product_2 cat5,cat1 |... `

Comment: Provide your output for now and desired output.

Comment: So now provide tables structure with sample data (best to make sql fiddle)

Comment: Would you be happy with returning a string with all the categories e.g. "1 cat1, 3 cat3, 6 cat6"?

Comment: @sr28 All the categories for a that product.

Comment: I understand that, but rather than having a column for each category, would you be happy to return the product name and another column which contains a string with all the categories for that product?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9866/2)

Comment: @sr28 Yes, but I don't want the redundancy of product records:  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9866/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the redundancy of the product records, in other words you only want the category information and nothing else, then you don't need the join to the main products table in the first place (assuming you're using the product id).

However, you're problem is that unless you're planning to display a column for every possible category and whether the product has it or not then you're going to need to do a work around. My preferred approach would be to create a cursor that runs through each row and pulls the categories for a given product id into a single string and puts this string into a new table (product id, categories).

```
DECLARE @productId int
DECLARE @prevProductId int
SET @prevProductId = 0
DECLARE @cid int
DECLARE @cname nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @categoryList nvarchar(max)
SET @categoryList = ''

DECLARE @ProdCatTable TABLE
(
    ProductId int,
    Categories nvarchar(max)
)

DECLARE category_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT pc.product_id, c.id, c.name
FROM categories c
JOIN product_categories pc
ON pc.category_id = c.id
ORDER BY pc.product_id

OPEN category_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM category_cursor
INTO @productId, @cid, @cname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @prevProductId = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @categoryList = @cid + ' ' + @cname
        SET @prevProductId = @productId
    END
    ELSE IF (@prevProductId <> @productId) AND @categoryList <> ''
         INSERT INTO @ProdCatTable (ProductId, Categories)
         VALUES (@prevProductId, @categoryList)
         SET @prevProductId = @ProductId
         SET @categoryList = ''
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @categoryList = @categoryList + ', ' + @cid + ' ' + @cname
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM category_cursor
    INTO @productId, @cid, @cname
END

CLOSE category_cursor
DEALLOCATE category_cursor

SELECT ProductId, Catgories
FROM @ProdCatTable
```

**NOTE**: This hasn't been tested, but I think it should work if you're happy to return a table with the product id as your identify and the categories as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. is this the best and optimized answer for this scenario ? I want to show each product with its categories.

Comment: As I say, I've not tested it. If you're only doing read only of the tables then perhaps a fast forward cursor would be better.

Comment: @Mike - Following on from comment above, there's not likely to be a tidy solution for this in any guise. If you had perhaps only 10 categories then it might be better to go down the route suggested in my second paragraph, which still isn't very nice but might perform better.

Answer (score 4):

You should add `WHERE` clause to specify ID and in select clause maybe you want to use `c.*` instead of `p.*` to get all data from categories.

```
select p.name, c.*  
from products p
join product_categories pc on pc.product_id = p.id
join categories c on pc.category_id = c.id
where p.id = --smth
```

Comment: OP needs data from categories as well

Comment: @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas I want to get a product and all of its categories

Comment: @Mike you can try `select p.name, c.* `, to get name of product and everything from categories, edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT        Tbl_Emp.EMPId, Tbl_Customer.First_Name, Tbl_Mail_IDs.MailId
FROM          Tbl_Emp INNER JOIN
      Tbl_Mail_IDs ON Tbl_Emp.EMPId = Tbl_Mail_IDs.Id INNER     
JOIN
      Tbl_Customer ON Tbl_Mail_IDs.Id = Tbl_Customer.Customer_Id
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks